# How can I select a different printer in a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I have a Web application programmed in C#.

There are several printers and  I want to choose any of them and execute the action, I would like some kind of Form to load all printers.

I found this for Win forms:

```
this.printDialog1.Document = this.printDocument1;

DialogResult dr =  this.printDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

But I couldn't find something for ASP.NET.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems like a pretty awful requirement.  Better to send emails with that which you'd be printing out.  That way 1) you don't miss anything  you would if the printer ran out of paper/ink 2) you don't just blindly dump stuff to a printer that will just be thrown away, saving moolah (screw the trees) 3) I like these lists to be in multiples of three so let me just end by saying that a web app that prints to a local printer is pretty dumb.

Comment: I can't do that I need a smart application, I mean the application should be able to recognize which printers are installed for that specific client and select them.

Comment: Web browsers don't let applications do anything like that (thank goodness).

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do it from a web app, if it was allowed then pop-up loving sites all over the internet would I'm sure be accounting for most of the worlds ink usage.

I had this issue when building a web app for a college, the most its possible to do is call up the print dialogue and have the user select the printer (best to have a decent print targeted CSS here):

```
javascript:window.print();
```

Its not perfect but to be honest although they insisted on it when it was put in a year ago, emails and PDF's are much more widely used.

Answer (score 0):

The printer is assigned at the workstation.

Comment: Heh - he wasn't asking if it was assigned - he was telling you that the user at the workstation picks the printer.  There is nothing a webpage can do to change that.